# SP2013 breadcrumbs on sub-sites without image

Tags: 2013, breadcrumb

On parent site, we have the breadcrumb working fine and the image URL for the breadcrumb is:

```
<img src="/_layouts/15/images/spcommon.png?rev=23" alt="Navigate Up" style="border-width:0;position:absolute;left:-215px !important;top:-120px !important;">
```

******Complete code snippet start

```
<div class="ms-breadcrumb-dropdownBox">
<span id="DeltaBreadcrumbDropdown">
<span class="ms-breadcrumb-anchor">

<span class="s4-clust" style="overflow: hidden; display: inline-block; position: relative;">

<a title="Navigate Up" id="GlobalBreadCrumbNavPopout-anchor" style="width: 16px; height: 16px; display: inline-block;" onmouseover="" onmouseout="" onclick="CoreInvoke('callOpenBreadcrumbMenu', event, 'GlobalBreadCrumbNavPopout-anchor', 'GlobalBreadCrumbNavPopout-menu', 'GlobalBreadCrumbNavPopout-img', 'ms-breadcrumb-anchor-open', 'ltr', '', false); return false;" href="javascript:;">

<img style="border-width: 0px; left: -215px !important; top: -120px !important; position: absolute;" alt="Navigate Up" src="/_layouts/15/images/spcommon.png?rev=23"></a></span></span>

<div class="ms-popoutMenu ms-breadcrumb-menu ms-noList" id="GlobalBreadCrumbNavPopout-menu" style="display: none;">
  <div class="ms-breadcrumb-top"><span class="ms-breadcrumb-header">This page location is:</span></div>

 <ul class="ms-breadcrumb">
 <li class="ms-breadcrumbRootNode"><span class="s4-breadcrumb-arrowcont"><span class="s4-clust s4-breadcrumb" style="width: 16px; height: 16px; overflow: hidden; display: inline-block; position: relative;"><img style="left: 0px !important; top: -289px !important; position: absolute;" alt="" src="/_layouts/15/images/fgimg.png?rev=23"></span></span><a class="ms-breadcrumbRootNode" href="http://test/">test PORTAL</a><ul class="ms-breadcrumbRootNode"><li class="ms-breadcrumbNode"><span class="s4-breadcrumb-arrowcont"><span class="s4-clust s4-breadcrumb" style="width: 16px; height: 16px; overflow: hidden; display: inline-block; position: relative;"><img style="left: 0px !important; top: -289px !important; position: absolute;" alt="" src="/_layouts/15/images/fgimg.png?rev=23"></span></span><a class="ms-breadcrumbNode" href="/sites/DocCenter">SharePoint 2013 Testing Document Center</a><ul class="ms-breadcrumbNode"><li class="ms-breadcrumbCurrentNode"><span class="s4-breadcrumb-arrowcont"><span class="s4-clust s4-breadcrumb" style="width: 16px; height: 16px; overflow: hidden; display: inline-block; position: relative;"><img style="left: 0px !important; top: -289px !important; position: absolute;" alt="" src="/_layouts/15/images/fgimg.png?rev=23"></span></span><span class="ms-breadcrumbCurrentNode">Home</span></li></ul></li></ul></li>
</ul>
</div>
</span>
</div>
```

******Complete code snippet end

If I have a subsite the inherits the parent's Seattle master page, the image URL for the anchor container:

is:

```
<img src="/sites/_catalogs/theme/Themed/760FD54F/spcommon-2D7B5F9E.themedpng?ctag=5" alt="Navigate Up" style="border-width:0;position:absolute;left:-215px !important;top:-120px !important;">
```

Any ideas?  Why is this happening on the subsite, as that image URL for the breadcrumb is giving a 404.

Comment: I just fixed this lol

Answer (score 2):

Here's what I had to verify to get the sub-site breadcrumb to work:

1. publishing is on for both parent and sub-site
2. specific .master page is set as default master page via SharePoint Designer
3. sub-site is inheriting parent master page via Look and Feel >> Master Page
4. sub-site is using the same template as the parent. We couldn't have different look @ the sub-site level...it had to use same as parent.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding this script before your closing tag:

```
<!-- Script to Retain Breadcrumb Icon -->
<script type="text/javascript"> 
  document.getElementById("GlobalBreadCrumbNavPopout-anchor").innerHTML='<img   style="border-width:0;position:absolute;left:-215px !important;top:-120px   !important;" alt="Navigate Up" src="/_layouts/15/images/spcommon.png?rev=27">';
</script>
```

You may check [here](http://academy.bindtuning.com/lets-bring-the-breadcrumb-back-to-sharepoint-2013/) for more info. You might need to modify the breadcrumb markup which can be found in the original seattle.master

Comment: It's not very evident that it was solved. Maybe you chould create a new Answer instead of adding to your post